# I am having trouble printing what I need to with inheritance using OOP

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

My code is as follows:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, Animal):
        print(Animal, "is an animal.")

class Mammal(Animal):
    def __init__(self, mammalName):
        print(mammalName, "is a warm-blooded animal")
        super().__init__(mammalName)

class NonWingedMammal(Mammal):
    def __init(self, NonWingedMammal):
        print(NonWingedMammal, "can't fly") 
        super().__init__(NonWingedMammal)

NonWingedMammal("Dog")
```

When I run this I am expecting the output

```
Dog can't fly
Dog is a warm-blooded animal
Dog is an animal.
```

However, I am getting the following output:

```
Dog is a warm-blooded animal
Dog is an animal.
<__main__.NonWingedMammal at 0x7fc340fee490>
```

I would have thought that `Dog can't fly` would have been part of my output because the search order goes from the derived class all the way down to the base classes - but it has seemed to skip the derived class? Obviously I have missed something here but can't figure out what!

Comment: you can't give your parameter the same name as the class and its `__init__` instead of `__init`

Comment: I'm voting to close this as typo/can't be reproduced, based on what @Sayse pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class NonWingedMammal(Mammal):
    def __init(self, NonWingedMammal):
        print(NonWingedMammal, "can't fly") 
        super().__init__(NonWingedMammal)
```

1. NonWingedMammal init misses ending `__`
2. You shouldn't name a parameter the same as class

Because of the typo in init, when you do `NonWingedMammal("Dog")`, you don't actually call what you wrote - because it's not `__init__`. Therefore, you call a default `__init__` - **which is inherited parent init**, giving the output:

```
Dog is a warm-blooded animal
Dog is an animal.
```

Line `<__main__.NonWingedMammal at 0x7fc340fee490>` is not really in the output - it is displayed only in interactive interpreter. Or if you do `print(NonWingedMammal("Dog")`.

**Fix: `__init(` -> `__init__(`**